# How to use an image as a link (which is stored as an expression in jinja templating) in HTML

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, jinja2-cli

I have a data expression which is called

```
img_tweets = ['http://pbs.twimg.com/media/EQYzCP4VAAEN0UJ.jpg']
```

In jinja

```
{{img_tweets}}
```

I want to use the value (which is a url) in img_tweets as an image for one of my pages. I'm not sure how to do that. This is what I have:

```
<img alt="img" src={{img_tweets}}
     width="150" height="70">
```

Please let me know if this is not clear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Jinja documentation](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/), attribute values need to be wrapped in quotes. So in your case, you'd write:

```
<img alt="Tweets" src="{{ img_tweets[0] }}" width="150" height="70">
```

Comment: hi, but img_tweets is a list.

Comment: how should i acess the value in img_tweets

Comment: To access the first item in a list, you can use `img_tweets[0]`

Comment: I tried that and the image did not appear, just a box appeared. Also, the number of items in the list varies since it is an api call so I won't be able to index. Should I do a for loop? Thanks for replying.